# HTML working in JSFiddle/W3 but not Tailwind

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to HTML and don't know why the code below works in some playgrounds but not others.

As stated in question, works in JSFiddle/W3 when I click one of the sections but not in Tailwind.
It to opens a new tab in Tailwind when I click section.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.vertical-menu {
  width: 200px;
}

.vertical-menu a {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".vertical-menu a");
  var activeItem = menuItems[0]; // Initial active item

  menuItems.forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      activeItem.classList.remove("active"); // Remove active class from previous active item
      activeItem = item; // Update active item
      activeItem.classList.add("active"); // Add active class to new active item
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="vertical-menu">
  <a href="#" class="active">
    #H1#
    <div class="subtitle">#S1#</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    #H2#
    <div class="subtitle">#S2#</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    #H3#
    <div class="subtitle">#S3#</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    #H4#
    <div class="subtitle">#S4#</div>
  </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As far as I can tell it is related to the concept of adding/removing classes.

Comment: Is the name ‘active’ of your class clashing with one in Tailwind?